# Susy: mixin applies, but throws error

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass, grid-layout

I just started to use Susy. When I apply span-columns() mixins, the markup does applies correctly, but sass throws an error: (Line 276: Undefined mixin 'span-columns'.)

```
#element-1 {
  @include span-columns(6, 12);
}
#element-2 {
  @include span-columns(6 omega, 12);
}
```

- Sass 3.3.0.alpha.3
- Compass 0.12.2
- susy-1.0.8

-- Edit: Fixed - it was me assuming that including Susy in a previously included scss file would be suffice to work in the last included scss file (which in a way it did). I included Susy again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you required Susy in the Compass config.rb file in the project folders root?

```
require "susy";
```

And have you imported Susy and Compass in the init of your scss file?

```
@import 'compass'; 
@import 'susy';
```