# Compass/Susy Error When Using at-breakpoint

Tags: susy-compass

Te error:

css/chpw.scss (Line 13: Mixin "at-breakpoint" does not accept a content block.)

The scss:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
@import "susy";

@include at-breakpoint(30em 12) {
  .page { @include container; }
}
```

No matter what I try at-breakpoint keeps breaking. Using ruby-2.0.0-p0 and compass-susy-plugin (0.9)
susy (1.0.8).

Comment: can you show more of the SCSS? When I remember correctly, @include is a mixin that needs to be used within a selector.

Comment: maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106477/susy-mixin-applies-but-throws-error

Comment: You need to uninstall the "compass-susy-plugin" gem. As long as it is installed, it will be used instead of the newer "susy" gem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on Windows 7. Eric Meyer's answer is correct. Typing `gem uninstall compass-susy-plugin` at the command line solved the problem.