# Compass compile error on Susy's at-breakpoint mixin

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm using Susy/Compass/SASS for a simple responsive grid on my current project. However, the Compass compiler won't compile Susy's at-breakpoint mixin. Here's my grid:

```
+border-box-sizing

$total-columns  : 3
$column-width   : 4.5em
$gutter-width   : 1em
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width
$container-style: fluid

$break-1: 6
$break-2: 10

body
    +container($total-columns, $break-1, $break-2)

.list
    +span-columns(3)
.detail
    display: none

+at-breakpoint($break-1) {
    .detail
        +squish(1)
        +span-columns(3)
    .list
        +span-columns(2 omega)
}

+at-breakpoint($break-2) {
    .detail
        +squish(1,1)
        +span-columns(5)
    .list
        +span-columns(3 omega)
}
```

When Compass tries to compile, I get an error: `error screen.sass (Line 20 of _grid.sass: Invalid CSS after "($break-1) ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "{")
identical screen.css`.

If found [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349148/compass-susy-error-when-using-at-breakpoint) similar to mine that suggested the `compass-susy-plugin` was the culprit. I have removed that (not sure that I had it to begin with) and installed the Susy gem again to be safe, but I still get the error.

Has anyone had this or a similar problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susy does support the indented Sass syntax. The problem is you're currently using a hybrid of both syntaxes. Try this:

```
@import "susy"

+border-box-sizing

$total-columns  : 3
$column-width   : 4.5em
$gutter-width   : 1em
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width
$container-style: fluid

$break-1: 6
$break-2: 10

body
    +container($total-columns, $break-1, $break-2)

.list
    +span-columns(3)
.detail
    display: none

+at-breakpoint($break-1)
    .detail
        +squish(1)
        +span-columns(3)
    .list
        +span-columns(2 omega)

+at-breakpoint($break-2)
    .detail
        +squish(1,1)
        +span-columns(5)
    .list
        +span-columns(3 omega)
```

Notice there are not curly brackets after the `at-breakpoint()` mixins. Just indent.

Answer (score -3):

I found the problem. Susy doesn't support SASS's indented syntax. Boo!

I added in tons of curly braces, semicolons, and `@include`s to fix it.

**UPDATE:**
OK, the problem was *not* support for the SASS syntax. It was my use of the curly braces in the indented syntax! For some reason, my brain decided that the code block would need to be in braces since it would be passed to a mixin. My mistake and my apologies to the devs of Susy.

Comment: All Sass plugins support both syntaxes. There's no way to support only one.

Comment: @EricMeyer Thanks for pointing out my error. Updated my answer above.